# How to draw markers between columns

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, columns

I have the following table of x and y values along with their first and second differences, however, I would like to place markers, in the form of two lines merging together like >, to show which values contribute to these differences. For example, 1 and 0 have a first difference of -1 and 0 and 3 have a first difference of +3 while the second difference between -1 and 3 is +4.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand*{\movedown}[1]{%
  \smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{#1}}}
\newcolumntype{q}{>{\collectcell\movedown}r<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{p}{>{\collectcell\movedown}q<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{rrqp}
        \toprule
            x & y & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$1^{st}$ difference} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$2^{nd}$ difference} \\
        \midrule
            0 & 1 & -1 & +4 \\
            1 & 0 & +3 & +4 \\
            2 & 3 & +7 & +4 \\
            3 & 10 & +11 & +4 \\
            4 & 21 & +15 & +4 \\
            5 & 36 & +19 \\
            6 & 55 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This is my table, however, I have no idea how to draw the markers at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply place something line `\rangle` into the table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand*{\movedown}[1]{%
  \smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{#1}}}
\newcolumntype{q}{>{\collectcell\movedown}r<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{p}{>{\collectcell\movedown}q<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{rrqqpp}
        \toprule
            x & y & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$1^{st}$ difference} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2^{nd}$ difference} \\
        \midrule
            0 & 1 & $\rangle$ & $-1$ & $\rangle$ & $+4$ \\
            1 & 0 & $\rangle$ & $+3$ & $\rangle$ & $+4$ \\
            2 & 3 & $\rangle$ & $+7$ & $\rangle$ & $+4$ \\
            3 & 10 & $\rangle$ & $+11$ & $\rangle$ & $+4$ \\
            4 & 21 & $\rangle$ & $+15$ & $\rangle$ & $+4$ \\
            5 & 36 & $\rangle$ & $+19$ \\
            6 & 55 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can also put your own custom symbol (you added the `tikz-pgf` tag to your question, but you don't need to use Ti*k*Z for such a simple drawing):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand*{\movedown}[1]{%
  \smash{\raisebox{-1ex}{#1}}}
\newcolumntype{q}{>{\collectcell\movedown}r<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{p}{>{\collectcell\movedown}q<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcommand{\join}{%
    \raisebox{.5ex}{%
        \begin{picture}(20,0)
            \put(20,0){\line(-5,1){20}}
            \put(20,0){\line(-5,-1){20}}
        \end{picture}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{rrqqpp}
        \toprule
            x & y & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$1^{st}$ difference} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2^{nd}$ difference} \\
        \midrule
            0 & 1 & \join & $-1$ & \join & $+4$ \\
            1 & 0 & \join & $+3$ & \join & $+4$ \\
            2 & 3 & \join & $+7$ & \join & $+4$ \\
            3 & 10 & \join & $+11$ & \join & $+4$ \\
            4 & 21 & \join & $+15$ & \join & $+4$ \\
            5 & 36 & \join & $+19$ \\
            6 & 55 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I need.